# SVG background of div is blurry with backgroundColor set

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to use svg as background for div element.

```
import backgroundHp from './../../assets/img/background_shapes_hp.svg'

<div className="layoutContainer" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundHp})`, backgroundColor: '#1a183e', backgroundPosition: 'center 310px' }}>
... content
</div>
```

css:

```
.layoutContainer {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

With this settings my background is blurry. It looks like it is not svg anymore. But when I don't set *backgroundPosition* my background is sharp. Left picture is with backgroundPosition set, right is without backgroundPosition.

What am I doing wrong? How can I set backgroundPositionbut and still get sharp background?

[image: backgroundPosition]

Comment: What browsers or other renders do you see this in?

Comment: @underscore_d . Thank you for good question. I have this problem in Chrome, Vivaldi, Edge, Opera.. only one browser show it good and that is Firefox..